# Prevent QuickLooking excel spreadsheet from crashing laptop

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur, quicklook

When I quicklook, accidentally/intentionally or thoughtlessly, some excel .xslx files in Finder (this one for example is "only" 272 KB, so maybe the problem is the large number of rows and columns or something else), it renders the file correctly in the quicklook window, but causes everything except my mouse pointer to freeze (can't scroll the preview, can't change window, can't change spaces, can't change any graphics on the display except mouse pointer position) and eventually a few minutes later my screen turns to multicolored static and the MacBook restarts. I can speed that up by closing and reopening the lid.

How can I stop this from happening? If possible I'd still like to be able to quicklook excel files that won't cause a crash, but if it is one that would cause a crash I would obviously not like to crash as a result of pressing space or an arrow key.

Quicklooking the csv equivalent of the xlsx does not cause a crash.

I do not have any MS Office programmes installed.

```
$ qlmanage -l
List of all generator IDs: (
    "com.apple.quicklookgenerator.iChat",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.package",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.pdf",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.audio",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.contact",
    "org.n8gray.qlcolorcode",
    "com.apple.garageband.quicklookgenerator",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.iCal",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.movie",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.image",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.livePhoto",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.web",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.LogicXQLGenerator",
    "com.apple.iBooks",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.certificates",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.bookmark",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.text",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.eps",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.clipping",
    "com.fiatdev.QLMarkdown",
    "fr.whine.qlimagesize",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.font",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.office",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.standard-bundles",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.iconset",
    "com.apple.iWork.iWorkQuickLookGenerator",
    "com.apple.qlgenerator.locPDF",
    "com.whomwah.quicklookstephen",
    "jp.co.celsys.LipPreview"
)
```

Comment: What version of Office do you have? Do any other file types cause crashes when QuickLooking? Can you provide the output of `qlmanage -l` in the Terminal? (that's an L, by the way.)

Comment: @benwiggy I updated the question with that info

Comment: The first thing I would do is remove (or disable) those third-party QL managers: n8gray, QLMarkdown, quicklookstephen, LipPreview. Remove them from the QuickLook folder in ~/Library or /Library. If they are bundled in an app, then that might be a bit more difficult.